# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier is crashing (found nil)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, ios-simulator

When I try to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` on an iPhone it is crashing the app, although this works fine on the ios simulator. The code I have used is:

```
let questionsGameVC: QuestionsGame = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") as! QuestionsGame
```

The error it is saying is

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can someone add anything to what is going wrong?

Comment: What errors is it crashing with

Comment: Sorry it says: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'

Comment: Well with that one line its impossible to tell but looks like you're trying to use something that has `nil` in it

Comment: But it works fine on a simulator just not on an iphone?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of places this could go wrong. I would put a breakpoint at that line and look at the state of the system, but debugging swift is still not in a great state. One alternative is to break apart that line of code and test all the pieces. Something like this:

```
if let storyboard = self.storyboard {
    if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") {
        if let questionGame = viewController as? QuestionGame {
            println("Success!")
        } else {
            println("Question game is the wrong type in the storyboard")
        }
    } else {
        println("There is no view controller with the identifier Questions")
    }
} else {
    println("The storyboard is nil")
}
```

Whatever gets printed at the end should give you a better idea of where the problem is. Most often I have seen misspelled identifiers or situations where the class of the view controller in the storyboard has not been changed from `UIViewController` to the custom type.

Comment: Nothing gets printed, it crashes on the line:  if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Questions") , I put a println in just before that line and it printed...

Comment: I just tested, and I apologize - my code crashed as well when there is no view controller with that identifier. I believe that is your issue. Can you confirm that the "Storyboard ID" of your `QuestionGame` view controller is "Questions"?

Comment: Thanks, Yep it 100% is "Questions". Like I said it works absolutely fine in the simulator just not on the iphone...strange...

Comment: Any other thoughts @Eric ?

Comment: I can't think of anything else off the top of my head without seeing the project. I don't suppose you have it in a repo somewhere? Or can reproduce the problem in a sample project that you could put in a public repo?

Comment: Sorted it now, the problem was something to do withe Cache, I just deleted the app and re-ran it and it worked :) thanks anyway thou

Comment: thanks Henry, I spent some hours on this weird issue. turns out the solution is nothing but just delete the app and re run it. I hate you Xcode :(